# How to search on a list using fulltextsqlquery?

Tags: list, search, fulltextsqlquery, path

```
SELECT Title, Path FROM Scope() WHERE \"Scope\"='All sites' AND CONTAINS(Path, '\site\Lists\ListDisplayName')
```

Is good syntax?